# Proving area equal to zero of a continuous function.

Tags: calculus, area

I'm kinda stuck with this exercise:

> Prove that the graph of a (uniformly) continuous function $f\:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ has area zero.

I was thinking that maybe I should use uniform continuity since it's continuous in a compact set => it's uniformly continuous there. But I'm really not sure on how to apply that to areas. And I believe, that a function (graph) has area equal to zero if it can be covered by a countable union of rectangles with area $\epsilon$. Not 100% sure though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't need countable union, as the area of countably many rectangles is not well-defined for an introductory course.

Fix an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, Choose $\delta$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon/2$. Then, choose a partition 
$$a=a_0<a_1<\ldots<a_n=b$$
such that the spaces between consecutive points is less than $\delta$. Then, the graph of $f$ lies inside the union of the rectangles of size $[a_i,a_{i+1}]\times[f(a_i)-\epsilon/2,f(a_i)\epsilon/2]$, which in total have area $\epsilon(b-a)$. So, the graph has area less than $\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$. Thus, it has area$=0$.

Comment: I'm assuming this question is not from a measure theory course. So, you don't have any rigorous definition of area; but, you appreciate the "obvious" properties of area like area of $A\cup B$ is equal to the sum of area of $A$ and $B$; and, $A\subseteq B$ implies area of $B$ is bigger than area of $A$.

Comment: Yes its not from a measure theory course, rather multivariable calculus. 
How do you get $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon/2$ ? Why did you choose $\epsilon/2$ ? 

Is the meaning of partitions the width of our rectangles that we use to cover our graph with? And how do we get the size of the rectangles to be $[a_i,a_{i+1}]\times[f(a_i)-\epsilon/2,f(a_i)\epsilon/2]$ ?

Comment: I get the inequality using the uniform convergence. I choose $\epsilon/2$, because I want the height of the rectangles to be $\epsilon$, as $|f(a)-f(b)|<\epsilon/2$ implies $f(b)\in\left[f(a)-\epsilon/2,f(a)+\epsilon/2\right]$, this is a rather technical detail. I choose the sizes of the rectangles in that way, because, I want to make use of the only possible tool(aka uniform continuity) in my hand. If $|a-b|<\delta$, by the uniform continuity, I know that for all $x\in [a,b]$ , $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon/2$ .

Comment: Is there a way to visualize that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon/2$ implies that the height of the rectangles is $\epsilon$ ? I have some trouble interpreting it formally.

Comment: What is the length of the following interval $\{y\in\mathbb{R}:|x-y|<\epsilon/2\}$?

Comment: x-$\epsilon/2$ < y <  x+ $\epsilon/2$ ?
So the length is x+ $\epsilon/2$ - ( x-$\epsilon/2$ )= $\epsilon$ ?

Comment: Okay , makes a bit more sense now. Also does the length in general correspond to the area in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, so the for any $x\in[a_i,a_{i+1}]$, $x-a_i<a_{i+1}-a_i<\delta$. Thus, $|f(x)-f(a_i)|<\epsilon/2$. In other words, $f(a_i)-\epsilon/2<f(x)<f(a_i)+\epsilon/2$. So, the graph of $f$ between $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$ is covered by the rectangle $[a_i,a_i+1]\times[f(a_i)-\epsilon/2,f(a_i)+\epsilon/2]$, becasue, $x\in [a_i,a_{i+1}]$ implies $f(x)\in[f(a_i)-\epsilon/2,f(a_i)+\epsilon/2]$. Lastly, as you said, this rectangle's width is $(a_{i+1}-a_i)$ and height is $\epsilon$. So, its area is $\epsilon(a_{i+1}-a_i)$. As $a_0=a,a_n=b$, when we sum all the areas up , we en up with $\epsilon(a-b)$

Comment: I have been looking at the area of the rectangles, and was wondering about something. Doesn't the total area sum up to: $(a_1 - a_0)\epsilon$ + $(a_2 - a_1)\epsilon$+.........+$(a_n - a_(n-1))\epsilon$ which in turn simplifies to $(a_n - a_0)\epsilon$ = $(b - a)\epsilon$ ?

Comment: Yes ,you're right.

Comment: Ok, but does this make a difference? Because b>a, so we could get a positive number times $\epsilon$ ? Does this still imply that the graph has area less than $\epsilon$ ?

Comment: No it does not make a difference and, I never claimed the area was under $\epsilon$. The area is under $(b-a)\epsilon$, which goes to 0 as $\epsilon\to0$

Comment: Okay.
Off topic: Is there a way to write a sub n-1 in MathJax in the correct way? $a_(n-1)$ looks kinda wrong.

Comment: In general, use { and } when you want to bracket things. So, a_{n-1} does $a_{n-1}$, exactly what you've asked for.