# Definition of an ordinate set; mistake in Apostol's Calculus?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

In page 114 of Apostol's Calculus, Vol. 1, exercise 7. says this

> Compute the volume of the solid generated by revolving the ordinate set of the function $f$ over the interval indicated. Sketch each of the ordinate sets $$ 7.\quad f(x) = \sin x + \cos x, \quad 0 \le x \le \pi$$

But notice that $f(x) < 0 $ for $x \in (3\pi/4,\pi).$ The definition of an ordinate set by Apostol is given on page 60-61:

> Let $f$ be a nonnegative function whose domain is a closed interval $[a,b].$ The portion of the plane between the graph of $f$ and the $x$-axis is called the *ordinate set* of $f$. More precisely, the ordinate set of $f$ is the collection of all points $(x,y)$ satisfying the inequalities $$a \le x \le b, \quad 0 \le y \le f(x).$$

This definition is then later expanded upon in page 75, where Apostol talks about the area of an ordinate set expressed as an integral. Specifically, he writes that

> Let $f$ be a nonnegative function, integrable on $[a,b],$ and let $Q$ denote the ordinate set of $f$ over $[a,b].$ Then $Q$ is measurable and its area is equal to the integral $\int_a^b f(x)\, dx.$

In any case, there is still a reference to “nonnegative” functions. However, if I look in the back of the book, then the answer is given as if we ignored this issue and integrated as a regular exercise.

Comment: I upvoted.  I own the same book, and I just reviewed it, first looking in the index for the term ordinate set.  From what I can see, you are right.  **Good question**.

Comment: See also [possible different mistake](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362951/zero-area-of-a-graph)

Comment: While the function is below X-axis between $3\pi/4$ and $\pi$, whether you need to break the bounds into two or not really depends on how you are finding the volume. What is the volume they came up with for the region between $0$ and $\pi$?

Comment: @MathLover $\pi^2,$ which is what you would get by computing $\int_0^\pi \pi(\sin x + \cos x)^2 ~ dx.$

Comment: OK but that is correct

Comment: @MathLover It's only correct if we ignore the definition of an ordinate set given by Apostol.

Comment: I added an answer. Pls see if that explains.

Comment: @user2661923 I am not sure if you noticed that the book was using a square function to integrate and find volume. The function never turns negative.

Comment: @MathLover You are missing the point of the query.  Quoting from the example at the bottom of page 113 in the book: "Let $f$ be a function which is non-negative...Then the area of the circular disk is $\pi[f(x)]^2$..." The only way to apply this definition to the problem is to **define** $g(x) = |f(x)|$, and then compute the volume of revolution of against $g(x)$.  From the bottom of p113 to the start of the problems on p114, Apostol never makes this point.  ...see next comment

Comment: @MathLover Certainly, this is both do-able and intuitively sensible, but for the beginning Calculus student who is justifiably paranoid about being rigorous, this situation becomes iffy.

Comment: @user2661923 ok understand from your comment now. Yes it should have differentiated between finding area using function $f$ vs. finding volume using $f^2$.